# FormCollection in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I want to detect if a window form is open and if it is then I would like to bring it in front rather than opening it again.

I know I need a form collection for this but I want to know if there is a built in form collection that holds all the forms in VB.NET or I need to implement my own.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
'Pass the form object (you could also use string as the 
'parameter and replace the if condition to: "If form.Name.Equals(targetForm) Then")
Public Sub BringToFront(ByVal targetForm As Form)
    Dim form As Form
    For Each form In Application.OpenForms()
        If form Is targetForm Then
            form.BringToFront()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Call this sub if you need to bring a specific form on front (only if it is already loaded) like this:

```
BringToFront(targetformobject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property.

Using LINQ:

```
Dim existingForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of YourFormType)().FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always  P/Invoke code to call into the user32 windows dll.  Something like this should do what you want.

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Public Shared SetFocus(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr)

Private Sub SetFocusToExistingWindow()

    Dim procs As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)

    If procs.Length > 0 Then
      Dim hwnd As IntPtr = procs(0).MainWindowHandle
      SetFocus(hwnd)
    End If

End Sub
```